# No default constructor for entity Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

i am creating simple crud application using student and task.i succussfully done the task save part.after save i need you get the record from database i got this error complete error i attached below.

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.SpringAppliction.entity.Task
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5324) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1643) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
```

what i treid so far i attached below.

**TaskController**

```
  @GetMapping(path="/getAllTasks")
  public List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks()
   {
       List<TaskDTO> allTasks = taskService.getAllTasks();
       return allTasks;
    }
```

**TaskDTO**

```
    public class TaskDTO {


    private Long  taskid;

    private String taskname;

    private String description;

    private Boolean complete;

    private long studentId;

    public TaskDTO(Long taskid, String taskname, String description, Boolean complete, long studentId) {
        this.taskid = taskid;
        this.taskname = taskname;
        this.description = description;
        this.complete = complete;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }


    public TaskDTO(String taskname, String description, Boolean complete, long studentId) {
        this.taskname = taskname;
        this.description = description;
        this.complete = complete;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }


    public TaskDTO(Long taskid, String taskname, String description, Boolean complete, Student student) {
    }

    public Long getTaskid() {
        return taskid;
    }

    public void setTaskid(Long taskid) {
        this.taskid = taskid;
    }

    public String getTaskname() {
        return taskname;
    }

    public void setTaskname(String taskname) {
        this.taskname = taskname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Boolean getComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    public void setComplete(Boolean complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TaskDTO{" +
                "taskid=" + taskid +
                ", taskname='" + taskname + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", complete=" + complete +
                ", studentId=" + studentId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**TaskService**

```
   List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks();
```

**TaskServiceIMPL**

```
@Override
public List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks() {
    List<Task> getTasks = taskRepo.findAll();
    List<TaskDTO> taskDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Task t:getTasks)
    {
        TaskDTO taskDTO = new TaskDTO(
                t.getTaskname(),
                t.getDescription(),
                t.getComplete(),
                t.getStudent()
        );
        taskDTOList.add(taskDTO);
    }
    return taskDTOList;

}
```

**TaskRepo**

```
public interface TaskRepo extends JpaRepository<Task,Long > {
}
```

**Entity**

```
    @Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "task_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long taskid;

    @Column(name = "task_name")
    private String taskname;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "complete")
    private Boolean complete;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    public Task(String taskname, String description, Boolean complete, StudentSaveDTO studentSaveDTO) {
    }


    public Task(long taskid) {
        this.taskid = taskid;
    }

    public Task(Long taskid, String taskname, String description, Boolean complete, Student student) {
        this.taskid = taskid;
        this.taskname = taskname;
        this.description = description;
        this.complete = complete;
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Task(String taskname, String description, Boolean complete, Student student) {
        this.taskname = taskname;
        this.description = description;
        this.complete = complete;
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Task() {
    }

    public Long getTaskid() {
        return taskid;
    }

    public void setTaskid(Long taskid) {
        this.taskid = taskid;
    }

    public String getTaskname() {
        return taskname;
    }

    public void setTaskname(String taskname) {
        this.taskname = taskname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Boolean getComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    public void setComplete(Boolean complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "taskid=" + taskid +
                ", taskname='" + taskname + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", complete=" + complete +
                ", student=" + student +
                '}';
    }
```

i added the entity aruguments

i checked trough the postman man

```
 {
        "taskid": null,
        "taskname": null,
        "description": null,
        "complete": null,
        "studentId": 0
    },
```

Comment: What the f***, `No default constructor for entity: com.example.SpringAppliction.entity.Task`. What more do you need? Add a default constructor to your Task class.

Comment: but fields are displayed as null

Comment: What are you arguing? Add a default constructor to your Task class !!! And if you don't understand the necessity of a default constructor for Hibernate, please take your time to learn about it.

Comment: how i added the argments i updated the code please can you check it

Comment: Looks good so far, with the exception, that you should not put the id (taskId) into the constructor since your strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY - thus the constructor which has only the taskId as parameter is completely useless.

Comment: Further, if there are no special reasons, I'd put `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` to the Task class itself. This makes it easier for Hibernate to fill the properties.

Comment: @Access(AccessType.FIELD) i put into the entity class but still null

Comment: Still the missing default constructor warning? And maybe you wanna update your question with the complete code classes, not only snippets containing some methods, that might also help to get a better understanding. Also, is the data correctly stored inside the db?

Comment: ya data is correctly saved in the db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254862/discussion-between-john-peter-and-slevin).